# Replication factor thumb rule

Tags: hadoop

I am aware that you decide the replication factor based on the system(transactional, general logs etc). But is there any rule of thumbe which we can follow or consider while deciding the replication factor?

Answer (score 0):

usually the main factors are

```
fault tolerance
Performance by reducing network traffic.
```

For the common case, when the replication factor is three, HDFS’s placement policy is to put one replica on one node in the local rack, another on a node in a different (remote) rack, and the last on a different node in the same remote rack. This policy cuts the inter-rack write traffic which generally improves write performance. The chance of rack failure is far less than that of node failure; this policy does not impact data reliability and availability guarantees. However, it does reduce the aggregate network bandwidth used when reading data since a block is placed in only two unique racks rather than three. With this policy, the replicas of a file do not evenly distribute across the racks. One third of replicas are on one node, two thirds of replicas are on one rack, and the other third are evenly distributed across the remaining racks. This policy improves write performance without compromising data reliability or read performance.